# Instanciar objetos de otra clase

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy realizando un proyecto y estoy estancado en uno de sus pasos.

- Tengo que instanciar un objeto de otra clase con su constructor vacío.
- Actualizar los atributos para ese objeto pidiéndolo por teclado y utilizando sus métodos set para iniciar sus atributos.

Mi código es el siguiente.

```
//Clase vehículo
public class Vehiculo { 
    
    //Declaración de los tipos enum
    public enum enumMarca {Renault, Ford, Mercedes, BMW, Toyota,Kia}
    public enum enumMes {Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre}
    
    //Declaración de atributos
    public String matricula;
    public enumMarca marca;
    public String color;
    public Integer klm;
    public int dia;
    public enumMes mes;
    public int anio;
    
    //Implementación del constructor que inicia el vehículo vacio.
    public Vehiculo () {
    
    }
    //Declaración de otro constructor que inicia todo los atributos de la clase
    public Vehiculo (String matricula, enumMarca marca, String color, Integer klm, int dia, enumMes mes, int anio) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
        this.klm = klm;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.anio = anio;
    }
    
    //Implementación de métodos que permiten acceder y modificar cada uno de los atributos de las clase.
    
    //Enums
    public enumMarca getMarca () {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(enumMarca marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    
    public enumMes getMes () {
        return mes;
    }
    public void setMes(enumMes mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }
    
    //Atributos
    
    //Matricula
    public String getmatricula () {
        return matricula;
    }
    public void setmatricula (String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    //Color
    public String getcolor () {
        return color;
    }
    public void setcolor (String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    //Kilometros
    public Integer getklm () {
        return klm;
    }
    public void setklm (Integer klm) {
        this.klm = klm;
    }
    //Dia
    public int getdia () {
        return dia;
    }
    public void setdia (int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }
    //Año
    public int getanio () {
        return anio;
    }
    public void setanio (int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }
    
    //Método para devolver una cadena con todos los valores del vehículo y con la fecha en formato largo.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String Vehiculo = dia + " de " +mes+ " de " +anio;
        return Vehiculo;
    }
```

**Esta es la clase vehículo.**

*Ahora, adjunto la **clase principal** en la cuál tengo que instanciar un objeto de la *clase vehículo*

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        
        //Instancia un objeto de clase vehiculo con el constructor vacio.
        
    }
}
```

Aquí me quedo estancando, intento instanciar un objeto con el siguiente código:

```
Vehiculo objVeh1 = new Vehiculo(String color.azul)
```

Pienso que este código esta mal, además necesito instanciarlo con el constructor vacío, el cuál en este caso, no se como realizarlo, ya que he repasado la teoría y no he sacado ninguna solución.

El código de arriba, lo he sacado viendo ejemplos y otros proyectos, pero creo que en mi caso no es el adecuado.

El objetivo de esto es probar la funcionalidad de la clase Vehiculo, desde la clase Principal, las dos están creadas en el mismo paquete.

Comment: Usar el constructor vacío es `Vehiculo v = new Vehiculo();`. Luego deberás usar `v.set...(...)` para añadir los distintos valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Método Main, con la clase vehículo, se instancia con constructor vacío, se lee por teclado y se valida con try catch, hasta que lo digitado sea correcto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean invalida = false;

    System.out.println("Datos de vehiculo");

    Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo();
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese la matricula del vehiculo");
    vehiculo.setmatricula(scanner.nextLine());

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese la marca del vehiculo");
            vehiculo.setMarca(enumMarca.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()));
            invalida = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("La marca no es valida");
            invalida = true;
        }
    } while (invalida);

    System.out.println("Ingrese el color del vehiculo");
    vehiculo.setcolor(scanner.nextLine());

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese los kilometros del vehiculo");
            vehiculo.setklm(scanner.nextInt());
            invalida = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Los kilometros no son validos");
            invalida = true;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    } while (invalida);

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el dia de la fecha de matriculacion del vehiculo");
            vehiculo.setdia(scanner.nextInt());
            invalida = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("El dia no es valido");
            invalida = true;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    } while (invalida);

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el mes de la fecha de matriculacion del vehiculo");
            vehiculo.setMes(enumMes.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()));
            invalida = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("El mes no es valido");
            invalida = true;
        }
    } while (invalida);

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el año de la fecha de matriculacion del vehiculo");
            vehiculo.setanio(scanner.nextInt());
            invalida = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("El año no es valido");
            invalida = true;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    } while (invalida);
    
    System.out.println(vehiculo.toString());
}
```

Prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué esto resuelve la pregunta? Además, el primer punto dice que con el constructor vacío. Es decir, así no va

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, con lo solicitado.

Comment: Hola, me ayuda mucho tu respuesta, pero, tengo que acabar sacando datos en la consola mediante el método toString, un ejemplo: Segundo vehiculo, inicializada con el segundo Vehículo
1204LTZ
Mercedes
Rojo
4.564 klm
La fecha es: 27 de Mayo del 2022
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Si usas netbeans hay una ayuda integrada, dentro del modelo (Vehiculo.java) con click derecho > generar código > toString(), allí marcas todas las propiedades y le das la forma que ocupas.